# Flurry Analytics(Android) не собирает статистику

Tags: android, статистика

Сделал (по статье на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/122510/)) все для подключения, как описывается (подключил нужные вещи, поместил все куда надо). Результат — ноль, в статистике никак не отражается, что я запускаю приложение, или выкидывает *Exception*. Инициализирую так:

```
    FlurryAgent.setContinueSessionMillis(60000);
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setCaptureUncaughtExceptions(true);
    FlurryAgent.init(this, "**************");
```

Запуск и остановка сессии происходит так:

```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   try {
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(getApplicationContext());
        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.ERROR);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Test",""+e);
    }

    throwError();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Test",""+e);
    }
}
```

ТруКатчи убирал - *Exception*  не кидает. В градле подключаю *jar* так:

```
//compile files('libs/FlurryAds-6.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/FlurryAnalyics-6.2.0.jar')
```

В логах обнаружил вот такое, не уверен что относится к проблеме:

> 01-29 14:23:44.416 6847-6867/com.ufanet.org.testtoolbar E/FlurryAgent:  GOOGLE  PLAY SERVICES EXCEPTION: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
>   01-29 14:23:45.417 6847-6867/com.ufanet.org.testtoolbar E/FlurryAgent: There   is a problem with the Google Play Services library, which is required for   Android Advertising ID support. The Google Play Services library should be   integrated in any app shipping in the Play Store that uses analytics or advertising.

Comment: А на устройстве Google Play Service установлены?

Comment: Да, установлены. Сначала пробовал на пустом планшете, потом на личном телефоне, где все установлено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я перенервничал, оказалось такие системы отображают информацию, о сессиях работы с приложением, через сутки(максимум).С кодом работал абсолютно верно.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, что все библиотеки стоят последние.
А у вас добавлена строка `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` ?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/57518)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, предложение проверить версии является ответом.